# Format indentation in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, legend

In the legend of this plot, I'd like "Box" and "ID" to be at the same distance from the left margin. Could you give me some hints on how to do it? Many thanks!

```
# Load packages and data    
library(ggplot2)

ID <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10))
Box <- c(rep("Red", 5), rep("Blue", 5), rep("Red", 5), rep("Blue", 5))
Time <- c(seq(1, 5), seq(1, 5), seq(1, 5), seq(1, 5))
Value <- runif(20, min=10, max=30)
dd <- data.frame(ID, Box, Time, Value)

# Plot
p1 <- ggplot(data = dd,
             aes(x = Time, y = Value, 
                 group = interaction(ID, Box),
                 shape = as.factor(ID),
                 colour=as.factor(ID),
                 linetype=Box)) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = 0.5, name = "ID",
                    labels = c("1", "2")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "ID",
                       labels = c("1", "2")) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Box", 
                          labels = c("Red", "Blue")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        aspect.ratio = 1, 
        text = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.position = c(0, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.key = element_blank())
plot(p1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to add `legend.box.just = 0` in `theme()`.